# Change session cookie name in Grails 3.0

Tags: session, grails, cookies, grails-3.0

In Grails 2.x you can change the name of the session cookie in the web.xml with

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <name>JSESSIONID_XYZ</name>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

In Grails 3.0 there is by default no web.xml (but can be created manually). Is there any other way to change the name of the session cookie?

Update: I tried to create a web.xml but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ServletContextInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletContextInitializer.html) can be used to register a bean, in which you can configure the Cookie name with

```
@Override
void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setName(sessionCookieName);
}
```

I preffed this solution because it also works during development with run-app, which is acutally what i need.

Comment: Where did you add that code? Some missing context on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works when deployed as a war, but not with run-app. Add this to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<web-app version='3.0'
         xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee'
         xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
         xsi:schemaLocation='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd'>

   <session-config>
      <cookie-config>
         <name>JSESSIONID_XYZ</name>
      </cookie-config>
   </session-config>

</web-app>
```

and deploy the war to Tomcat or another container and it will use the config settings from web.xml along with the programmatic servlet/filter/etc. registrations.

Comment: the problem with this solution that it must work also with run-app. I'm developing an web-app that consists of two parts that run as seperate apps and there is a conflict with the session cookie when both app are accessed via the same domain name (e.g. localhost)